# Excel VBA get file list from current folder by type

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel macro to get the file list by type from current folder.

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()

Dim varDirectory As Variant
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim strDirectory As String

strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
i = 1
flag = True
varDirectory = Dir("C:\Macro\*.txt", vbNormal)

While flag = True
    If varDirectory = "" Then
        flag = False
    Else
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = varDirectory
        varDirectory = Dir
        i = i + 1
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

This works fine. But I want to make two modifications:
1. Change the path name in

```
varDirectory = Dir("C:\Macro\*.txt", vbNormal)
```

to active workbook path. When I tried to change it and I got errors. I don't know how to combine

> Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

with the .txt file type condition.

2. I want to print the results in cells  starting from B2, B3, B4...

Could somebody please help me fix these two issues?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code that you tried that didn't work.  We need to see what the exact error was caused by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. change `varDirectory = Dir("C:\Macro\*.txt", vbNormal)` to `varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory, vbNormal)`
2. change `Cells(i + 1, 1) = varDirectory` to `Cells(i + 1, 2) = varDirectory`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what error you got when running the code with the ActiveWorkbook but if you use the following code it should work. And for the second issue, you should change the second parameter of Cells from 1(A) to 2(B).

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()

Dim varDirectory As Variant
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim strDirectory As String

strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
i = 1
flag = True
varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory & "*.pdf", vbNormal)

While flag = True
    If varDirectory = "" Then
        flag = False
    Else
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = varDirectory
        varDirectory = Dir
        i = i + 1
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the varDirectory string seems to work fine when I try to "immediate" it so I don't think there are errors there.

Just set

```
strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.txt"
```

and change this:

```
    Else
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = varDirectory
    ' this is... unnecessary: varDirectory = Dir
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: The line `varDirectory = Dir` is very necessary as it is what creates the loop.  Without that line, the loop would be endless.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Comment: It is very important to include that parameter, without which you get unlimited number of results.